# Arduino : Check byte array for chars one at a time

Tags: serial-port, arrays, arduino, handshake

I communicate with Arduino via Serial using a program that sends a series of bytes.

In order for the Arduino to realize it is receiving a message rather than junk, I have tagged the start of my byte array with the chars 'S' 'T' 'A' 'R' 'T'. After this will eventually follow a series of bytes that will be assigned to internal variables (not yet implemented).

The Arduino must read each byte sequentially and compare it to the byte array and if all are present in the correct order it will continue with the next part of the program, otherwise it will should discard current byte and wait for more bytes to arrive.

I am trying to implement it in the most efficient and readable way rather than using a series of nested if statements.

So far I have got:

```
byte inByte = 0;
byte handShake[] = {'S','T','A','R','T'};

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() 
{
  while (Serial.available()) 
{
  for (int x =0; x < sizeof(handShake) ; x++)
    {
    inByte = Serial.read();
    Serial.println(x);
    if (inByte == handShake[x]) 
     {
        if (x == (sizeof(handShake)-1)) {setArduino();}  
      }
       else break;
   }
  }
}


void setArduino () {
  Serial.println("Ready To Set Parameters");
}
```

This however doesn't seem to get past the second byte and I'm not sure why.

Comment: It is more common simply to use a control char (ex: *) to signify the end of a message. Unless your setup is doing something unusual, the likelihood of receiving junk serial chars is small.

Comment: I do seem to get some junk chars a few times when connecting so this way I will be sure it is the right message. The probability of triggering a read on just one char is 1/256 or 0.3% but reading 100 times per second comes to 30% chance of error per second where as using my 5 chars is 1/1099511627776 or 9x10^-11% which reading 100 times per second is 9X10-9% per second which i can live with.

Comment: Just trying to use a belt and braces approach, I will also add and error check byte to the end of the data packet to protect against bad data. Yes, this may be over kill but for practice imagine this micro-controller is operating an essential system, you really don't want the wrong message getting through.

Comment: I have found it works if I add a delay(5); after the second if statement to allow the next byte to arrive, however I don' think this is the best way to do it. I really need the program to pause and wait for the next byte after the first rather than wait for an arbitrary length of time. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Worked it out :

Here is the answer:

```
byte inByte = 0;
char handShake[] = {'S','T','A','R','T'};

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() 
{
  while (Serial.available()) 
  {
  for (int x =0; x < sizeof(handShake) ; x++)
    {
    inByte = Serial.read();
    Serial.println(x);
    if (inByte == handShake[x]) 
      {
       if (x == (sizeof(handShake)-1)) {setArduino();}  
       while(!Serial.available()) {delay(1);}
      }
       else {break;}
    }
  }
}


void setArduino () {
  Serial.println("Ready To Set Parameters");
}
```

This may not be the most efficient way perhaps, but I can't see a problem with it currently.

Comment: ok there is a problem with this: if it only recieves "ST" it will wait indefinately for the next byte rather than executing other code in the loop() which will eventually contain pin checks. So this is no good.

Comment: Are you sure ? I don't have an Arduino at hand to check this, but I don't think it's blocking.

Answer (score 1):

Better answer : This allows the rest of the loop to iterate while waiting for the message to finish and if the full handshake message isn't received the counter will reset.

```
byte inByte = 0;
char handShake[] = {'S','T','A','R','T'};
int messageIndex = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() 
{
  while (Serial.available()) 
  {
    inByte = Serial.read();
    Serial.println(messageIndex);
    if (inByte == handShake[messageIndex]) 
      {
        messageIndex++;
        if (messageIndex == sizeof(handShake)) {messageIndex = 0; setArduino();}  
      }
       else {messageIndex=0;}
  }
// Other code while waiting for message to finish
Serial.println("tick");
}


void setArduino () {
  Serial.println("Ready To Set Parameters");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to calculate your message. CRC is old and good solution. I use it and it works perfect for me. I am not sure what kind of device are you communicating with.

```
//define
const uint32_t Polynomial = 0xEDB88320;
const uint16_t NumBytes = 256;
uint8_t data[NumBytes];

/// compute CRC32
uint32_t crc32_bitwise(const void* data, uint16_t length, uint32_t previousCrc32 = 0)
{
  uint32_t crc = ~previousCrc32; // same as previousCrc32 ^ 0xFFFFFFFF
  uint8_t* current = (uint8_t*) data;

  while (length--)
  {
    crc ^= *current++;
    for (uint8_t j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    {
      uint8_t lowestBit = crc & 1;
      crc >>= 1;
      if (lowestBit)
        crc ^= Polynomial;
    }
  }
  return ~crc; // same as crc ^ 0xFFFFFFFF
}
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:    
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:    
}
```

when you need to calculate CRC

`uint32_t crc = crc32_bitwise(data_bytes, sizeof(data_bytes));`

`data_bytes` is byte array.

Then you can get all settings or message in `byte data[x]` and calculate CRC. Then you can add CRC to the message and send message `byte data[x+sizeof(CRC)]`

P.S. Use `byte` instead of `int`. For ex. `for(byte x =0; x<sizeof(handShake); x++)`